# MYSQL database will not allow any more table field data to be inserted

Tags: php, mysql

I have a basic MYSQL query, that I am playing with and testing some API data, the problem is that for some reason, whilst the database is being populated perfectly by the test information, If i add any new fields the database simply doesn't insert any data in to them.  I have tried several different fields and tried to add even simple data.

My latest attempt is trying to insert a value in to the hostname field, but again whilst it inserts data in to all of the other fields it skips this one?

```
 INSERT INTO vistordetails1 
            (ipaddress, hostname, client_id, type, date_time, company_name, location, search_term,    trafic_source, no_of_pages, country_code) VALUES('$ip_address', '1', '$client_id', '$type', now(),'$fields[11]','$fields[6]', '$keyword', '$referer','1','$country_code')
```

Ok so I changed the code to this, to replace the values

```
INSERT INTO vistordetails1 
            (ipaddress, client_id, type, date_time, company_name, location, search_term, trafic_source, no_of_pages, country_code) VALUES('1', '1', '1', now(),'1','1', '1', '1','1','1')
```

Ok so now I have corrected the code as above when i copy and paste this in to PHP MY ADMIN i get no issues, it inserts all of the values except for the field hostname, which was that last table field i added.

Comment: What is the primary key in the table, and does it have any unique indexes? Try printing the query result and execute it in PHPMyAdmin or some similar kind of software.
You should get some kind of error which will indicate what's going wrong

Comment: You appreciate that you cannot just add a new field to the insert statement - you need to update the table first with the new field?

Comment: You absolutely need to have access to error messages. Seriously.

Comment: if we have your mysql error message that might help us

Comment: How does `,'$country_code'` get converted into `,1'`? This cannot be your real code.

Comment: I changed the variable because i added the query through phpmyadmin to test it and it wouldn't have a value for the variable

Answer (score 2):

missing quote at the end `1`

```
INSERT INTO vistordetails1 
            (ipaddress, client_id, type, date_time, company_name, location, search_term, trafic_source, no_of_pages, country_code) VALUES('1', '1', '1', now(),'1','1', '1', '1','1','1')
```

Comment: thanks that was actually a typo on my behalf, when i corrected that and checked it against the original code i posted.

Answer (score 1):

You missed the semicolon at the end.Please check.This might causes error. and add quote at the last '1'.You missed that.